# How to get game time if RL day has 6 game days?

Tags: php, time

My problem is this: My game day is supposed to be 1/6 of a real world day. A game day has 12 game hours. Thus one game hour is 20 minutes real time. Or that's what it's supposed to be. However, when I've observed the time, instead of an hour being 20 minutes, it's in fact 30 minutes. I can't figure out what's causing this. What's wrong with my function?

```
public function getGameTime() {

  $t = time();
  $d = $t/60/60/6 - 68646;//the number taken off makes the current time day 200 instead of a really big number
  $fraction = $d - floor($d);
  if ($fraction<(1/12)) $hour = 0;
  else if ($fraction<(1/12)*2) $hour = 1;
  else if ($fraction<(1/12)*3) $hour = 2;
  else if ($fraction<(1/12)*4) $hour = 3;
  else if ($fraction<(1/12)*5) $hour = 4;
  else if ($fraction<(1/12)*6) $hour = 5;
  else if ($fraction<(1/12)*7) $hour = 6;
  else if ($fraction<(1/12)*8) $hour = 7;
  else if ($fraction<(1/12)*9) $hour = 8;
  else if ($fraction<(1/12)*10) $hour = 9;
  else if ($fraction<(1/12)*11) $hour = 10;
  else $hour = 11;
  for ($minute = 59; $minute>=0; $minute--) {
    if ((($hour*60+$minute)/720)<$fraction) {
      $min = $minute;
      break;
    }
  }
  return array(
  "day" => floor($d),
  "hour" => $hour,
  "minute" => $min
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your subtraction in `$d = $t/60/60/6 - 68646;`. The comment does not help...

Comment: Looks like a homework question. What have you done to debug into this?

Comment: If I didn't reduce anything, it would make the current game day 68846. I want to start from a smaller number, so I'm using the reduction to make the day smaller. Technically it could be any number as long as it doesn't make the current day negative. The hours and minutes would still get calculated the same no matter if the day is 68846, 200 or 1, so that part is actually irrelevant. To debug I have observed what time the hour changes, and currently it's on top of the hour and at 30 past. If it functioned the way expected, it would be :00, :20 and :40.

Comment: ...I guess I should be dividing by 4 instead of 6? I can't wrap my brain around this, but if one hour needs to be 20 minutes real time then that seems to do it.

Answer (score 0):

So yes, if I want 6 four hour periods in a day I need to divide by 4. Dividing by 6 gives me four 6-hour periods instead. Because the divisor is the number of real life hours in a game day, not the number of game days in 24 hours. Problem solved.